# Running .pkg installer fails through Script Editor, but works in Terminal

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line

I'm trying to use Script Editor to create a clickable app that downloads a script, runs the script (which uninstalls a piece of software that isn't working properly), downloads a new .pkg installer, and then runs that .pkg. I'm trying to use terminal commands through AppleScript to do this.

Here's the AppleScript code:

```
do shell script "cd ~/Downloads;curl -O https://my.url/jumpcloud-fix.sh;sudo sh jumpcloud-fix.sh" with administrator privileges

do shell script "cd ~/Downloads;curl --no-progress-meter -O https://my.url2/jumpcloud-agent.pkg;sudo /usr/sbin/installer -pkg jumpcloud-agent.pkg -target /" with administrator privileges
```

When I test it out by pressing the play button in Script Editor to run the code, everything is working perfectly right up until the last step of running the installer. The installer appears to run, but then fails with the following message:

```
error "installer: Package name is JumpCloud Agent
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer: The upgrade failed. (The Installer encountered an error that caused
the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance. An
error occurred while extracting files from the package “jumpcloud-
agent.pkg”.)" number 1
```

However, when I actually open Terminal and input the commands below to run the exact same .pkg that was downloaded, it works and the GUI for the installer launches.

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo /usr/sbin/installer -pkg jumpcloud-agent.pkg -target /
```

Any ideas why the installer isn't working through the Applescript code in Script Editor, but seems to be working just fine with the same commands in Terminal?

Comment: From the error message, it appears that the installer is trying to write to the root (`/`) directory which is write protected.  What message do you get when running from Terminal?

Comment: When I run it through Terminal, I get the following message.

installer: Package name is JumpCloud Agent
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer: The upgrade was successful.

So it appears to work just fine through Terminal.

Comment: What is shown when the additional [debugging flags](https://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/8/installer/) `-dumplog` and `-verbose` are added? What difference appears in the output of `/var/log/install.log`?